# Batch copy files to SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, vba, file-upload, vbscript, automation

I searched SO, SU, and [SP.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) for a solution, but could not find what I needed. I'm looking for a solution which may be a script **or** some other non-coding method/tool.

I am trying to write a script (to be used by others) or some other form of automation to upload various reports automatically to a SharePoint site. I have managed to get the following (VBScript) code to work, but only for text-based files -- .CSV in this case, though this also works for .TXT, etc.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sCurPath
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
UploadAllToSP sCurPath

Sub UploadAllToSP(sFolder)
    Dim fso, folder, fil
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    For Each fil In folder.Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(fil) = "csv" Then
            UploadFileToSP fil
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub UploadFileToSP(ofile)
    Dim xmlhttp
    Dim sharepointUrl
    Dim sharepointFileName
    Dim tsIn
    Dim sBody

    Set tsIn = ofile.openAsTextstream
    sBody = tsIn.readAll
    tsIn.close
    sharepointUrl = "http://SHAREPOINT URL HERE"

    sharepointFileName = sharepointUrl & ofile.name
    set xmlHttp = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
    xmlhttp.open "PUT", sharepointFileName, false
    xmlhttp.send sBody
    If xmlhttp.status < 200 Or xmlhttp.status > 201 Then
        wscript.echo "There was a problem uploading " & ofile.name & "!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This only works for text files because it pipes the text data into a file on the SP site. However, if I want to transfer any kind of binary file (.XLS, .PDF), this results in garbage being uploaded.

I tried to take a look at a `Shell.Application` ==> `.Namespace()`, but this doesn't seem to work with a URL, but only a physical drive. Here's some of what else I tried (trimmed to show relevant pieces):

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

If oApp.NameSpace(sharepointUrl) <> Null then ' Always Null!
    ' Copy here
    ' Some lines omitted
    oApp.NameSpace(sharepointUrl).CopyHere ofile.Name ' This also fails when not surrounded by the Null check
Else
    MsgBox "SharePoint directory not found!"
End If
```

I also tried a batch file using xcopy, but that can't connect to the `http://` either. I looked at [this method](http://my.re-invent.com/helpdesk/KB/a222/how-do-i-copy-many-files-at-once-to-my-sharepoint-2003.aspx), which may work for me, but I'd prefer not to deal with mapping/`NET USE`, since our company has multiple network shares, the mapping for which varies depending on who's logged in.

Since none of these work quite the way I need: **Is there a method to automate this kind of functionality?**

I have experience with VBA/VBscript, so either a script like the above, or something built in to an MS Office application (Outlook is best, but I can probably adapt whatever I am given) would be preferable. That being said, I am open to any method that would allow me to do this, running natively in Windows or Office. However, I do not have access to Visual Studio, so I can't use any .NET functionality.

Comment: used `upload sharepoint vba` on google to find this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1b26aca0-4579-4cc3-bdaa-ea945452db01/

Comment: @SeanCheshire I did see that already, but the details of the answer include creating a C# class. As I noted in the Q, I don't have access to Visual Studio and thus can't use this option as far as I am aware.

Comment: look down the page to dg_moore's answer

Comment: I see that now. :-/ Sorry. Looking into that option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Sean Cheshire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039730/batch-copy-files-to-sharepoint-site#comment16073151_12039730) for pointing me at the obvious answer that I did not see. Posting the relevant code, since I don't believe this yet exists on SO.

```
Sub UploadFilesToSP(sFolder)

Dim sharepointUrl
Dim sharepointFileName
Dim LlFileLength
Dim Lvarbin()
Dim LobjXML
Dim LvarBinData
Dim PstrFullfileName
Dim PstrTargetURL
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fldr
Dim f

    'This has not been successfully tested using an "https" connection.
    sharepointUrl = "http://SHAREPOINT URL HERE"
    Set LobjXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)

    For Each f In fldr.Files
        sharepointFileName = sharepointUrl & f.Name

        PstrFullfileName = sFolder & f.Name
        LlFileLength = FileLen(PstrFullfileName) - 1

        ' Read the file into a byte array.
        ReDim Lvarbin(LlFileLength)
        Open PstrFullfileName For Binary As #1
        Get #1, , Lvarbin
        Close #1

        ' Convert to variant to PUT.
        LvarBinData = Lvarbin
        PstrTargetURL = sharepointFileName 

        ' Put the data to the server, false means synchronous.
        LobjXML.Open "PUT", PstrTargetURL, False

        ' Send the file in.
        LobjXML.Send LvarBinData
    Next f

Set LobjXML = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is VBA code, formatted to mostly work with VBScript, though I could not get this block to transfer properly. As VBA, this can be improved some by assigning data types, etc.

```
' Read the file into a byte array.
ReDim Lvarbin(LlFileLength)
Open PstrFullfileName For Binary As #1
Get #1, , Lvarbin
Close #1
```

Comment: @bill I updated a comment in the code. This may or may not work. I tried it myself by simply changing the `http` to `https`, but it just hangs my system at `LobjXML.Send LvarBinData`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old post but a very useful one so thanks to everyone's contribution. This is my version with the early binding. I found that the previous posting didn't work due to VBA assumption of the none declared variable types.

```html
Private Sub cmdUploadToApplicationsAndApprovals_Click()

    Dim strSharePointUrl As String
    Dim strSharePointFileName As String
    Dim lngFileLength As Long
    Dim bytBinary() As Byte
    Dim objXML As XMLHTTP
    Dim varBinData As Variant
    Dim strFullfileName As String
    Dim strTargetURL As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim strFolder As String
    
    strFolder = CurrentProject.Path & "\Upload\"
        
    'This has not been successfully tested using an "https" connection.
    strSharePointUrl = "http://sps.mysite.ca/subsite/DocLib/"
    Set objXML = New XMLHTTP 'CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)

    For Each file In folder.Files
        strSharePointFileName = strSharePointUrl & file.Name

        strFullfileName = strFolder & file.Name
        lngFileLength = FileLen(strFullfileName) - 1

        'Read the file into a byte array.
        ReDim bytBinary(lngFileLength)
        Open strFullfileName For Binary As #1
        Get #1, , bytBinary
        Close #1

        'Convert to variant to PUT.
        varBinData = bytBinary
        strTargetURL = strSharePointFileName

        'Put the data to the server, false means synchronous.
        objXML.Open "PUT", strTargetURL, False

        'Send the file in.
        objXML.Send varBinData
        
        'Now Update the metadata
        
        
    Next file

    'Clean up
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

FYI the above code required 2 references.
1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Hope this helps improve on the already brilliant answer!!