# Kill statement does not work in Sharepoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, kill

Calculations kept by users are stored as "ToCheck..." on sharepoint. Once checked the file is than renamed to "Checked...". I am trying to delete the now superfluous "ToCheck..." file.
First this code:
    Dim spMap As Object, spPath As String

```
Set spMap = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
spMap.MapNetworkDrive "X:", spPath
DoEvents

Kill (Pad & Naam)
```

.
.

and later other code from internet (after ticking in tools/references MS scripting)

```
Dim fs As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
With fs
    If .FileExists(yourfilepath) Then
        .DeleteFile yourfilepath
    End If
End With
.
.
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  In the second example does the `DeleteFile` line actually run?

Comment: nothing. But I found code that does work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955831/deleting-sharepoint-files-using-xmlhttp